# Implement Android navigation back button in maui blazor hybrid

Tags: maui-blazor

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace WINITMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            var isConfirmed = DisplayAlert("Leave Page", "Are you sure you want to leave this page?", "OK", "Cancel").Result;

            if (isConfirmed)
            {
                return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to control android navigation back button for that I wrote the above code. But it is not working. `OnBackButtonPressed` this method is not hitting.

I want to handle android navigation back button in .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid

Comment: There is a similar thread here:[Override/Disable Android Back Button in Blazor Hybrid MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594926/override-disable-android-back-button-in-blazor-hybrid-maui).